Having to manually start gdm everytime
I recently installed lightdm, Big mistake. It was terrible, So i then un-installed it using systemctl remove lightdm.service.
However, I am still having issues. First  is that on startup it still has the purple ubuntu unity logo. But the main issue is that, Gdm doesnt start. I have to manually start it using systemctl restart gdm in the command screen.
I even did systemctl edit gdm and tried putting:
[Service] 
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 1

To add a delay in when gdm starts, Still no luck. Anybody knows why this is happening?

You've not told us what release you're using, and you've tagged & mention two different desktops.  Your plymouth screen (screen that hides boot messages) will remain the same until you change it; it isn't changed even if you remove the package that installed it (as that could break something, it thus remains unchanged until you change it). You don't clearly say what you've done, to your unstated system.  FYI:  Like the plymouth screen, have you told your system to use gdm3 via command, as its not done by package installs/removals (directly anyway)

Whilst I don't know what you did (not what you're actually running), but if you apt install lightdm on a system, you likely triggered a question that asks which DM you wish to use, and that was set as default (eg. lightdm)...  If you subsequently remove the package lightdm that will not change your default; you've in effect still got lightdm as default but your removal means it cannot actually run (as it's not there).  You can correct via sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3  but that doesn't explain changes to your plymouth screens.....
